# Getting blob data from database using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I try to get a blob out of a database using camel (2.15.1). The data size is about 20 mb. This is my route:

```
<route streamCache="true">
    <from uri="file://c:/tmp/trigger" />
    <to uri="jdbc:datasourceCosima" />
    <log message="done 1."/>
    <to uri="direct:a" />
</route>

<route streamCache="true">
    <from uri="direct:a" />
    <to uri="file:blobdata" />
    <log message="done 2."/>
</route>
```

To start it i place a file with the sql command in c:/tmp/trigger. The content is something like `select bls_data from blob_storage where io_id='2fe0...'`

This is the result:

```
[2016-02-18 12:44:15.539] INFO: org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger log - done 1. 
[2016-02-18 12:44:16.553] SEVERE: org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger log - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-GHD13044-49732-1455793836517-2-2382 on ExchangeId: ID-GHD13044-49732-1455793836517-2-2381). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileMessage@7a0613]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route9            ] [route9            ] [file://c:/tmp/trigger                                                         ] [      1635]
[route9            ] [to13              ] [jdbc:datasourceCosima                                                         ] [       822]
[route9            ] [log12             ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[route9            ] [to14              ] [direct:a                                                                      ] [       813]
[route10           ] [to15              ] [file:blobdata                                                                 ] [       812]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-GHD13044-49732-1455793836517-2-2381
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-GHD13044-49732-1455793836517-2-2380, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=c:\tmp\trigger\select.txt, CamelFileContentType=null, CamelFileLastModified=1455793414658, CamelFileLength=179, CamelFileName=select.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=select.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=select.txt, CamelFileParent=c:\tmp\trigger, CamelFilePath=c:\tmp\trigger\select.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=select.txt, CamelJdbcColumnNames=[bls_data], CamelJdbcRowCount=1, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
    BodyType            java.util.ArrayList
    Body                [{bls_data=255044462D312E360D25E2E3CFD30D0A3...
]

Stacktrace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileMessage@7a0613]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1635)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:308)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:433)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I thought that `streamCache` would do the job and cache the data on disc or whatever.

So the question is: How to get blob data from a database into a file without size restriction?

Comment: You trying to save `java.util.ArrayList` to file. Maybe problem  is in an implicit data type conversion.

Comment: Try to set the `outputType` to `StreamList`.

Comment: @Ralf: As i understand it the jdbc component gets the data from the database and creates an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`. How to change that to a `StreamList`?

Comment: `jdbc:datasourceCosima?outputType=StreamList`